# React - update child when parent state changes, without using componentWillReceiveProps()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm building a JSON editor in React and the library I'm using doesn't have a `componentWillReceiveProps` hook. I'm somewhat new to React and trying to instantly update the `<Editor />` component when the parent state changes.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { JsonEditor as Editor } from "jsoneditor-react";

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      originalData: [],
      newData: []
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.resetForm = this.resetForm.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: ["original data"],
      originalData: ["original data"],
    });
  }

  handleChange(val) {
    this.setState({
      newData: val
    });
  }

  resetForm() {
    this.setState({
      data: this.state.originalData // this *does* update the state but the <Editor /> component doesn't reflect it.
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="Home">
        <main>
          <button onClick={this.resetForm}>
            Reset
          </button>
          <Editor // no componentWillReiveProps available
            value={data}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You'd need to share the Editor component as well for a specific answer, but if it can't react to prop changes then you need to perform that functionality when parent state changes and pass the value down as another prop. Alternatively if you can convert to a functional component and use hooks instead then `useMemo` will do the same thing as `componentWillRecieveProps` - [more info](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html).

Comment: @lawrence-witt it's a pretty robust editor. Here's the repo: https://github.com/vankop/jsoneditor-react

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise it was a dependency. None of what I posted is really relevant then, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any state updaters inside the child component, you can use `key`

It fully unmount and mount component.

```
<Editor
   key={this.state.data}
   value={this.state.data}
   onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may make it work:

```
this.setState({
      data: [...this.state.originalData] 
});
```